# AEM social Communities Handlebars context

Tags: handlebars.js, aem

I'm trying to get a context named **userAdmin** from within the handlebars framework for AEM Social Communities. The userAdmin context checks if the logged in user is a member or a moderator.

We already have this code within /libs/social/console/components/hbs/sitenavbar/**sitenavbar.hbs** at line number 54. With the below userAdmin context the Administration link appears only if the logged in user is a moderator/Community Admin

```
{{#if userAdmin}}
    <li><a href="{{adminUrl}}">{{i18n "Administration"}}</a></li>
{{/if}}
```

**Problem**

I'm not able to fetch the same **userAdmin** context within /libs/social/messaging/components/hbs/messagebox/buttons.hbs at line number 36 where I want to the new message button only if the logged in user is a moderator/Community Admin

```
{{#if userAdmin}} //Here the context is not available within the buttons.hbs
   <input type='submit' class='actionbuttons' id='newMessageButton' name='{{properties.replyURL}}' value='{{i18n "+ New Message"}}' />
{{/if}}
```

Could you please help me to figure out a way to get the context available in sitenavbar to any other SCF component like messagebox or forums. I've also tried using options like {{../userAdmin}} and {{@root userAdmin}}

Any suggestion or help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This data (or getter) is exposed through the [SocialComponent](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/communities/scf/server-customize.html#SocialComponent%20Interface) for this resource type. Only few objects are implicit available globally. So you need to define your own social component and implement (or extend existing component if some bundle exports it) such a getter. You can refer to the example scf projects (for example [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-scf-sample-components-extension/blob/master/bundles/aem-scf-extensions/src/main/java/com/adobe/aem/scf/extensions/IdeaSocialComponent.java)) in [github](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/) or look also in the [adobe documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/code-samples.html).

You can find all objects available in the context of the current path by appending .social.json (e.g. /content/community-components/en/forum/jcr:content/content/forum.social.json).This will expose all the variables (context) that can be used inside the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot @d33t for the guidance, appreciate it!

Comment: @BharathValse please vote up and accept the answer if it suits your needs and answers your question. thanks